# XmlDocument file name with space

Tags: c#, xml, service, xmldocument

I have XML file that contains services names in windows7, one of the services has white space i.e "service name" I get exception when I load the file:

```
fileName = file;
pathToFile = path;
XmlDocument ServerList = new XmlDocument();            
ServerList.Load(pathToFile + fileName);
```

the XML:

```
<systems>
 <Groups>
  <Myervices>    
     <Dialogic/>
     <BoardServer/>
     <HmpElements/>
     <Service-1 Agent/>
   </Myervices>
 </Groups>
</systems>
```

the filenName has the white space, is there a way to receive it cause I cannot change the service name.

the exception I get:

> '/' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='. Line 824,
>   position 23. at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e) at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args) at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowUnexpectedToken(String
>   expectedToken1, String expectedToken2) at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributes() at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement() at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent() at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() at
>   System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace) at
>   System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc) at
>   System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean
>   preserveWhitespace) at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
>   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename) at
>   Stop_Start_systems.Functions..ctor(String path, String file) in
>   c:\Stop_Start_systems\Functions.cs:line 32 at
>   Stop_Start_systems.Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\Stop_Start_systems\Default.aspx.cs:line 31
>   System.Collections.ListDictionaryInterna Thanks

Comment: Well *what* exception do you get?

Comment: Please include the *full* exception message (including the name of the exception, and ideally the stack trace). It sounds like the XML file is invalid though - look at line 824, column 23...

Comment: I add there the service name that i get from windows : "service-1 agent"

Comment: But have you looked at the XML file in question, line 824? What's generating the XML file anyway?

Comment: I put the names manually in the xml file - I copy it from the service names that is written from services

Comment: Well it sounds like you've constructed a broken XML file then. We have no idea what the file looks like, making it hard to suggest a fix.

Comment: getting this err when I use service name that contains a space

<service-1 Agent/>

Comment: In other words, the space in the filename has _nothing_ to do with the problem. Only that you have hand-edited the XML, to ***include*** the filename, and that you have **broken** it!

Comment: the file is good cause it works with all other names just when I add this name with the white space I get this exception

Comment: Well, since the XML is the problem, maybe you had better _show_ us some of the XML in question. Do **not** post all thousand lines of it.

Comment: @ishigh: No, the file is *not* good. That is invalid XML. You can't have a space in an XML element name. It's as simple as that. I would suggest using the same element name for all services, and put the sercice name as an attribute value.

Comment: I add the XML @Jon Skeet this is the name that I get from the services names - I don't know how to change it in windows services

Comment: @ishigh: I didn't suggest changing the service nice. I suggested changing your XML, which is simply invalid at the moment.

Comment: @ishigh as @Jon Skeet said, you cannot have this. Here `Agent` will be read as an attribute and you have an error because every attribute must be follow by a "=". The error is clear `The expected token is '='.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the name of the XML file, or the code you posted. It has everything to do with the XML being invalid. XML element names can't contain spaces, so this isn't valid:

```
<Service-1 Agent/>
```

Instead, you should use the same element name for all services, putting the service name into an attribute instead, e.g.

```
<Service Name="Service-1 Agent" />
<Service Name="Some other service" />
```

etc. I would strongly advise you to create the XML file automatically using an API instead of by hand - that way you're *much* more likely to end up with valid XML.